# Is the dotnet5.4 TFM forward compatible to RC2?

Tags: asp.net-core, dnx50

If I were to release a new version of a library with support for the dotnet5.4 moniker, will it be consumable from .NET Core 1.0 RC2 or will I need to explicitly release a new version that targets netstandardX?

(I realise these monikers aren't actually equivalent, its more about maintaining support for .NET Core)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"dotnet" monikers are [mapped](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1691) to "netstandard", so you should use dotnet for now.

Note that dotnet5.4 is a little restrictive in that it *only* [runs](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/project-docs/standard-platform.md#observations) on .NET Framework 4.6 or later, Universal Windows Platform 10 (UWP), DNX Core 5.0 and Mono/Xamarin platforms.

EDIT: According to [David Fowler](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/53) my original answer is incorrect and "dotnet" and "netstandard" **are not interchangeable** [anymore](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/pull/209). You'll need to import dotnet5.x explicitly.

```
{
    "frameworks": {
        "netstandard1.5": {
            "imports": "dotnet5.6",
            "dependencies": {
            "SomeDependency": "1.0.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, that mapping link was exactly what I was searching for. So, to clarify, dnx/nuget will apply these mappings automatically as of rc2?

Comment: The mapping is dependent on a new release of NuGet (release 3.4 I  think). No release date on that yet. But at the moment "dotnet" support works fine.

Comment: Not quite. It maps but it will not be compatible. You'll need to force compatibility using the imports feature in project.json

Comment: More detail on @davidfowl's comment here: https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/53

Answer (score 0):

Update based on [a conversation on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/53) with @davidfowl

Essentially, the answer us "no, dotnetX libraries will not automatically be consumed by rc2+ projects targetting netstandardX".

However, NuGet (circa rc2) will support an "imports" property in project.json, that will include other targets with a framework. The feature has been [described](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1962) as "go away NuGet, I know what I want"

For example, to include dotnet5.4 libraries in your netstandard1.3 project build, you would use:

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.3": {
      "imports": "dotnet5.4"
    }
  }
}
```